# Selecting specific columns using laravel eager loading doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am really not getting why this eager loading is not working when I try to return specific columns. 
This code works perfectly

```
$user=User::where('userName', $userName)
        ->with('points')
        ->with('examstaken')
        ->with('question')
        /*->with(array('points'=>function($query){
                $query->select('id','points');
         }))*/
         ->get();
```

This code doesn't wort

```
$user=User::where('userName', $userName)
        /*->with('points')*/
        ->with('examstaken')
        ->with('question')
        ->with(array('points'=>function($query){
                $query->select('id','points');
         }))
         ->get();
```

Doesn't work mean, 'points' doesn't return any value while the first one return the values correctly..

Any idea what's wrong with it?

Here is the relation in my user model

```
  public function points()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Points','user_id');
}
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 5):

Ok solved it. It seems I have to pass the user_id, the foreign key and then they it will work. Posting it as answer as someone else may get help :)

```
$user=User::where('userName', $userName)
        /*->with('points')*/
        ->with('examstaken')
        ->with('question')
        ->with(array('points'=>function($query){
                $query->select('user_id','points');
         }))
         ->get();
```

Comment: if you don't select the keys needed for the relationship, Eloquent wont be able to match up the children to their parents by key